# systemd-logind spams in log

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, systemd

In `/var/log/auth.log` appears too many messages `Removed session`

```
Jun  2 17:42:39 srv-1 systemd-logind[13785]: Removed session c36006.
Jun  2 17:42:39 srv-1 systemd-logind[13785]: Removed session c36007.
Jun  2 17:42:40 srv-1 systemd-logind[13785]: Removed session c36008.
Jun  2 17:42:41 srv-1 systemd-logind[13785]: Removed session c36009.
Jun  2 17:42:41 srv-1 systemd-logind[13785]: Removed session c36010.
Jun  2 17:42:41 srv-1 systemd-logind[13785]: Removed session c36011.
Jun  2 17:42:42 srv-1 systemd-logind[13785]: Removed session c36012.
Jun  2 17:42:43 srv-1 systemd-logind[13785]: Removed session c36013.
Jun  2 17:42:43 srv-1 systemd-logind[13785]: Removed session c36014.
Jun  2 17:42:43 srv-1 systemd-logind[13785]: Removed session c36015.
Jun  2 17:42:44 srv-1 systemd-logind[13785]: Removed session c36016.
Jun  2 17:42:45 srv-1 systemd-logind[13785]: Removed session c36017.
Jun  2 17:42:45 srv-1 systemd-logind[13785]: Removed session c36018.
Jun  2 17:42:46 srv-1 systemd-logind[13785]: Removed session c36019.
Jun  2 17:42:47 srv-1 systemd-logind[13785]: Removed session c36020.
Jun  2 17:42:48 srv-1 systemd-logind[13785]: Removed session c36021.
```

and no message about New session, i can't understand what causing this problem

```
uname -a
Linux backup-01 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 'if ($programname == "systemd" or $programname == "systemd-logind")'\ 
' and ($msg contains "Starting Session" or $msg contains "Started Session"'\
' or $msg contains "Created slice" or $msg contains "Starting user-"'\
' or $msg contains "New session" or $msg contains "Removed session")'\
' then stop'>/etc/rsyslog.d/ignore-systemd-session.conf

systemctl restart rsyslog
```

run it in the console to create a file with the settings to stop spam

Answer (score 0):

I found, it causing by `service zabbix-agent start` command,
if i start zabbix agent via `/etc/init.d/zabbix-agent start` anything similar does not occur.